# Integration testing and images

Tags: python, image, unit-testing, language-agnostic, integration-testing

I'm writing an app that converts different images to JPG. It operates over a complex directory structure. There, a directory may include other directories, image files (JPG, GIF, PNG, TIFF), PDF files, RAR/ZIP archives, which in turn may include anything of the above. The app finds everything that can be converted to an image and places the resulting JPGs into a separate folder.

How do i write integration tests to test the conversion of images? Specifically, how should i fake the complex directory structure with all the files?

Currently i just store a sample directory structure, which i manually assembled out of various image, PDF and archive files, in a `tests/` directory. In a `setUp` method i put this sample directory in place of the actual data and run the code. I had an idea to generate all these sample files myself (generate JPGs via Imagemagick, for example), but it proved hard.

How integration testing on images is usually done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you write your own library to convert images of you just use existing library? In the latter case you simply do not test it. Author has already tested it somehow. You just need to create an abstraction layer between your code and the image library you use. Then you can simply check if your code calls the library with desired parameters.
If you really insist on testing pictures then you need to make the transformation deterministic (and compare actual result with expected result) or you need to make comparison a bit less strict (from ignoring date fields to OCR recognizing the image).

Testing files is way easier (you do not need probability based OCR).Check if your program placed all files in expected location.